# Unable to change the selected rage in Material Date-Rangepicker

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I need to style a material date range picker with custom colors, I'm not able to find which class corresponds to the selected range

[image]

I've found the selected and changed with

```
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-selected {
    background-color: #368EA1;
}
```

anyone can help me please?

I also need to change the background color when passing over the items

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a new handy browser feature in `Chrome` called `Css Overview`. It gives you an overview of the styling properties used in the page components and native `html` elements. Among these properties it extracts the colors. From the list of the colors extracted there, pick the `mat-calender-range` color you want to change and it will give you the name of the classes associated with this color. Here is a screenshot of how this can be used with `mat-calender`.

[image]

Comment: excuse me in your screen I don't see mat-calendar-range....  I have a ```mat-calendar-body-in-range``` do you mean this?